# Meteor или Node.js + Socket.io + MongoDB + Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Существует задача по созданию крупного проекта, веб-приложения с риалтаймом. Создавая новый проект в ВебШторме, уже почти нажав на "Node.js app" увидел ниже "Meteor App". Название понравилось, загуглил и тут полились кисельные реки о том, как же хорош Meteor. В нём уже всё с коробки, всё удобно, не нужно ничего настраивать, кода мало, садись и пиши.
Можно ли запускать большое приложение на Meteor'е? И может ли он полностью заменить весь стек технологий, который я перечислил в заголовке?

Answer (score 1):

Заменить может. Но для крупного проекта надо неплохо знать подводные камни meteor, иначе проблемы с производительностью полезут.
Другими словами, если вы не работали с meteor, крупный проект лучше на нем не реализовывать.